# Xcode 11 Beta 6 UISearchBar textfield background color

Tags: uitextfield, uisearchbar, ios13, xcode11

Any idea how to set the UISearchBar textfield's background color separately from the search bar's tintcolor?

```
[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[XYNavigationController class]]].barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

results in
[image]

And even if you try:

```
[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class], [XYNavigationController class], [UINavigationBar class]]].layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;

[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class], [XYNavigationController class], [UINavigationBar class]]].backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class], [XYNavigationController class], [UINavigationBar class]]].tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
```

the textfield's background color won't change to orange. 
Is this a bug or something different needs to be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For changing searchBar's text field background color, use UISearchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor property added in iOS 13

Comment: is this possible to do through the appearance proxy api?